# Как переопределить метод у объекта, получаемого не из конструктора?

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Есть нижеследующий код

```
imageSlider = new SliderLayout(rootView.getContext()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    imageSlider = (SliderLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slider);
```

Собственно, мне необходимо переопределить метод *onInterceptTouchEvent*, но, что вполне очевидно, я сначала получаю ссылку на объект через конструктор, а потом ссылку на объект через *findViewById* . Так как же тогда мне, при получении ссылки из *findViewById*, переопределить метод *onInterceptTouchEvent*?

***UPD:***

Спасибо всем ответившим!

Решил проблему следующим образом:

**ExtendedSliderLayout.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout;

public class ExtendedSliderLayout extends SliderLayout {

public ExtendedSliderLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExtendedSliderLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExtendedSliderLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true;
}

}
```

**JoinFragment.java**

```
ExtendedImageSlider imageSlider;
imageSlider = (ExtendedSliderLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slider);
```

Мой пост, кстати, объясняет, как запретить пользователю самому менять картинки свайпом в [AndroidImageSlider библиотке](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Вы не можете в рантайме изменять уже скомпилированный класс.

Вам надо создать свой отдельный класс, расширяющий/копирующий целевой класс и использовать в разметке его, а не текущую реализацию. Так вы будете из разметки получать класс с нужным вам поведением

---

Ну или вы можете переопределить класс способом из начала вашего вопроса и программно добавить его в разметку экрана. Т.е. формировать экран программно, не в xml-разметке

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае вы создаете объект, который является экземпляром анонимного класса наследника `SliderLayout`. Соответственно, Вы можете определить и переопределить любые методы у этого класса.

Во втором случае Вы получаете ссылку на уже созданный объект, все методы которого уже определены.

Соответственно, если Вы хотите переопределить какой-то метод, то Вам нужно найти место, где **создается** этот объект и сделать его объектом другого класса

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться паттерном проектирования **декоратор**.

Т.е. если у вас есть *аннонимный класс*, и вы хотите изменить поведение для объектов данного класса, то следует создать класс реализующий данный интерфейс. При этом, часть интерфейсных методов будет иметь собственную реализацию, а часть, делегировать вызов методам исходного объекта.

Выглядит это будет следующим образом
Есть интерфейс:

```
interface MyInterface {
    int firstMethod();
    int secondMethod();
}
```

Есть какой то метод, возвращающий объекты, реализации данного интерфейса:

```
private MyInterface method() {
    return new MyInterface() {
        @Override
        public int firstMethod() {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public int secondMethod() {
            return 1;
        }
    };
}
```

Тогда, вам нужно создать декоратор для данного класса:

```
private static class DecoratorMyInterface implements MyInterface {
    private final MyInterface instance;

    public DecoratorMyInterface(MyInterface instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }


    //изменили реализацию для данного метода
    @Override
    public int firstMethod() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int secondMethod() {
        return instance.secondMethod();
    }
}
```